# Find the homotopy fibre of the map $\pi$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

Find the homotopy fibre of the map $\pi : X \vee Y \rightarrow X$ given that $\pi ( X, *) = X$ and $\pi ( *, Y) = *$, I was given a hint to use the second cube theorem but I do not know how to build the squares, could anyone help me please?

Comment: I don't know what a "second cube theorem" is, but if I had to guess, the answer by Jesse McKeown is what you want:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134814/what-is-the-homotopy-fiber-of-a-fold-map

Comment: @JasonDeVito the second cube theorem is in the book called "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory" by Jeffery Strom on pg.320

Comment: $X\vee Y$ is the (homotopy) pushout of $X\leftarrow\ast\rightarrow Y$ (assuming $X,Y$ are well-pointed). Pull back the path fibration over $X$ by the map $\pi:X\vee Y\rightarrow X$. Restricting $\pi$ to $X$ you get the identity (and you know the homotopy fibre of this map). Restricting to $Y$ you get a null-homotopic map (and you know the homotopy fibre of this map). At the back of the cube you get the homotopy fibre of the unique map $\ast\rightarrow X$ (and you know its homotopy fibre too). Check that the maps in the top square are what your expect and you'll get the answer.